# Cmake undefined reference to 'cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, cmake

I created a small program to test OpenCV C++ with Cmake and visual studio code but the build failed because of undefined functions and I don't know why Here is my code and my CmakeList.txt
I have already set the variable paths like this :

```
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\bin
C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;
int main()
{

    Mat img = imread("lena.jpg");
    imshow("IMAGE", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(TP1 VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(TP1 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(TP1 ${OpenCV_LIBS})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Build output using cmake tools in vscode

```
[main] Building folder: TP1 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/amine/Desktop/My_Studies/OpenCV/TP1/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 10
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target TP1
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/TP1.dir/main.cpp.obj
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable TP1.exe
[build] CMakeFiles\TP1.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `main':
[build] C:/Users/amine/Desktop/My_Studies/OpenCV/TP1/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
[build] C:/Users/amine/Desktop/My_Studies/OpenCV/TP1/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
[build] C:/Users/amine/Desktop/My_Studies/OpenCV/TP1/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
[build] CMakeFiles\TP1.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `cv::Mat::~Mat()':
[build] C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:751: undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
[build] CMakeFiles\TP1.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `cv::Mat::release()':
[build] C:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:863: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
[build] collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\TP1.dir\build.make:115: TP1.exe] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:370: CMakeFiles/TP1.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:120: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Location of opencv

```
C://opencv
```

Location of my code sample

```
Desktop//My_studies//OpenCV//TP1
```

Comment: The path `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc15\lib` suggests that OpenCV has been built for **Visual Studio 15**. These binaries are **incompatible** with **MinGW**, for which your build your project. You need either OpenCV binaries for MinGW, or build the project for Visual Studio. (I don't know whether Visual Studio Code is able to build projects using Visual Studio`s compiler.)

Comment: so i need to change my OpenCV version to a lower version or what can I do except downloading visual studio ?

Comment: The problem is not in OpenCV version. The problem is that you have downloaded OpenCV binaries, which are suitable only for Visual Studio and cannot be used in MinGW. You need to download OpenCV binaries suitable for MinGW. In other words, a single OpenCV version could be distributed (in binary form) for multiple platforms. You need to download those binaries, which are suitable for platform you are programming for.

Comment: You don't need to `include(CTest)` here. Just `enable_testing()` is enough. There's no such variable as `CPACK_PROJECT_NAME`, it's called `CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME` and you don't need it anyway because it takes its default from the project command, so you can just drop both those `set()` calls. Never use `include_directories` (use `target_include_directories` instead). Don't call `target_link_libraries` without a visibility specifier (eg. `PRIVATE`). Don't set the minimum version lower than your minimum tested version (no way is that 3.0).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I compiled OpenCV using VS17 , yet build my program with VSCode...I receive the same error as him...So I guess you can't build OpenCV's program u=outside of your compiling engine

Comment: @AmirulAkmal: "...yet build my program with VSCode" - While Visual Studio 17 provides both a build tool and acompiler, VSCode is not a **compiler**. Whether Visual Studio will be able to use your library, built in VSCode, depends on the actual compiler you configured for VSCode. E.g. if you configure VSCode to use MinGW and `gcc`, then Visual Studio cannot use resulted library. But if you configure VSCode to use Ninja and `cl` compiler, the resulted library could perfectly be used in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Tsyvarev hehe, sorry...I need to repair my words....I build at VSCode ,using `task.json` and `g++.exe`...and yeah , apparently it's true that when I compiled using Visual Studio and I can't make the use of the lib....Althought , last night I've recompiled with `mingw32` and my program compiled .Thank you